# Javascript prototype constructor explanation

Tags: javascript, function, oop, object, constructor

I have the following code snippet which represents the answer to this question:

You are creating a class named Consultant that mustinherit from the Employee class. The Consultant class must modify the inherited PayEmployee method. Future instances of Consultant must be created withthe overridden method.

```
function Employee() {}

Employee.prototype.PayEmployee = function ( ){
  alert(‘Hi there!’);
}

function Consultant () { 
  Employee.call(this);                            // X
}
Consultant.prototype = new Employee(); 
Consultant.prototype.constructor = Consultant;    // X

Consultant.prototype.PayEmployee = function () 
{ 
  alert(‘Pay Consultant’); 
}
```

I really can't wrap my head around this. Why are lines marked with "X" necessary? Couldn't I just write the code without these lines and it would be exactly the same? According to my tests it would make no difference:

- https://jsfiddle.net/yk84g8f4/1/
- https://jsfiddle.net/66jxp9p9/

Can someone explain me what the difference between these two codes is, and what why I should use one over the other?

Thanks in advance

Comment: *currently* they may not show any difference. Try define other properties and methods on base class `Employee` but not `Consultant`, I beleive you will find something :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Couldn't I just write the code without these lines and it would be exactly the same?

No, you do need both of them in the general case. Yes, in some specific cases, you can get away without one or both of them.

First off, note that that code has a common error in it. This is incorrect:

```
Consultant.prototype = new Employee(); // INCORRECT
```

It should be:

```
Consultant.prototype = Object.create(Employee.prototype);
```

`new Employee` does two distinct things:

1. It creates an object that uses `Employee.prototype` as its prototype
2. It runs the code in `Employee`, whose job is to initialize an instance of `Employee` by setting up properties and such on `this`

But we don't want that second part yet. `Consultant.prototype` isn't an `Employee` *instance*, it's an object that *will become* the prototype of an object created via `new Consultant` (which will be an instance of `Employee`, and also of `Consultant`). (This is where JavaScript's constructor functions and `prototype` property depart from standard prototypical inheritance. You can do standard prototypical inheritance in JavaScript, but when you do, you don't use constructor functions, the `prototype` property, or `new`.)

`Object.create` just does the first of those two tasks: Creates an object using `Employee.prototype` as its prototype. So we end up with an object on `Consultant.prototype` that uses `Employee.prototype` as its prototype, but *without* calling `Employee` and having it run its per-instance initialization code. (We do that later, in the second line you marked with an X.)

But why don't we want `Employee` to do its per-instance initialization? Because, again, `Consultant.prototype` isn't an `Employee` instance, so it doesn't make sense to initialize it as one. For one thing: What if `Employee` requires parameters it uses to initialize the object it returns? What would we pass it when constructing `Consultant.prototype`? We don't have any instance-specific information to pass it at that point.

So instead, we just do #1 above (via `Object.create`), and leave #2 (calling `Employee`) until we're constructing an instance, by calling `Employee.call(this)` from `Consultant` (more below).

---

To your marked lines:

```
Employee.call(this);
```

This line is essential to give `Employee` its chance to do its initialization of the instance being created. Without it, `Employee` hasn't had a chance to do its job: Initialize the `Employee` parts of the instance. For instance, suppose `Employee` looks like this:

```
function Employee() {
    this.paySchedule = "biweekly";
}
```

Without the `Employee.call(this);` line in `Consultant`, that property would be missing from an instance created via `new Consultant`.

Your second marked line:

```
Consultant.prototype.constructor = Consultant;
```

We need to do this because `Consultant.prototype`'s `constructor` property should point to `Consultant`, but if we don't do this, it will point to `Employee`.

It didn't used to matter much, because although `constructor` was defined in the specification to be set up this way by default, nothing in the specificaton used to use it. That changed in ES2015 (aka "ES6"): Now, the `constructor` property is used sometimes (for instance, in promises).

---

Here's an example illustrating the situation where `Employee` has parameters. I've also switched `PayEmployee` to `payEmployee` to be in keeping with the overwhelming convention in JavaScript that only constructor functions are initially-capped:

```js
function Employee(name, title) {
    this.name = name;
    this.title = title;
}

Employee.prototype.payEmployee = function() {
    console.log("Time to pay " + this.name + " (" + this.title + ")");
};

function Consultant(name) {
    Employee.call(this, name, "Consultant");
}
Consultant.prototype = Object.create(Employee.prototype);
Consultant.prototype.constructor = Consultant;

Consultant.prototype.payEmployee = function() {
    console.log("Time to pay " + this.name + " (" + this.title + ") -- remember, you're paying the gross, consultants handle their own tax.");
};

var e = new Employee("Joe Bloggs", "Engineer");
e.payEmployee();

var c = new Consultant("John Smith");
c.payEmployee();
```

---

And finally, I'd be remiss if I didn't point out that as of ES2015, we have `class` syntax for this, which can be transpiled if necessary for older environments:

```js
class Employee {
    constructor(name, title) {
        this.name = name;
        this.title = title;
    }
    payEmployee() {
        console.log("Time to pay " + this.name + " (" + this.title + ")");
    }
}

class Consultant extends Employee {
    constructor(name) {
        super(name, "Consultant");
    }
    payEmployee() {
        console.log("Time to pay " + this.name + " (" + this.title + ") -- remember, you're paying the gross, consultants handle their own tax.");
    }
}

const e = new Employee("Joe Bloggs", "Engineer");
e.payEmployee();

const c = new Consultant("John Smith");
c.payEmployee();
```

---

You asked about whether `Consultant.prottype = new Employee();` is always wrong. Let's take a version of the code using `new Employee` for that, and removing the two lines you marked with X, and add a feature to Employee that seems like it should work, but ends up leading to all kinds of confusion:

```js
function Employee() {
    this.staff = [];
}

Employee.prototype.payEmployee = function() {
    console.log("Paying employee");
};

function Consultant(name) {
}
Consultant.prototype = new Employee();

Consultant.prototype.payEmployee = function() {
    console.log("Time to pay " + this.name + " (" + this.title + ") -- remember, you're paying the gross, consultants handle their own tax.");
};

var jill1 = new Employee();
jill1.staff.push("Bob");
jill1.staff.push("Jane");

var john1 = new Employee();
john1.staff.push("Russell");
john1.staff.push("Mohammed");

console.log("Jill's staff (1): " + jill1.staff.join(", "));
console.log("John's staff (1): " + john1.staff.join(", "));

// so far so good, but what if we use Consultant instead?

var jill2 = new Consultant();
jill2.staff.push("Bob");
jill2.staff.push("Jane");

var john2 = new Consultant();
john2.staff.push("Russell");
john2.staff.push("Mohammed");

console.log("Jill's staff (2): " + jill2.staff.join(", "));
console.log("John's staff (2): " + john2.staff.join(", "));

// ??? how is it they both have all four staff?!
```

The problem is that the `staff` array is on `Consultant.prototype`, not each instance, and so regardless of which instance we use, we're always accessing the same array.

That's why we don't use functions intended to initialize *instances* (e.g., constructor functions) to initialize the object for a constructor function's `prototype` property.

I should note that in standard prototypical inheritance, it would be common and normal to actually create an instance to be a prototype of another instance. But JavaScript's constructor functions and their `prototype` property are not standard prototypical inheritance, they're a hybrid of class-based OOP and prototypical OOP. You can do pure prototypical OOP in JavaScript (and many do), but when you do, you don't use constructor functions, their `prototype` property, or `new`. You use factory functions and `Object.create` (usually).

Comment: Thank you very much for your great explanation! Thanks to you I do understand the logic behind this now. 

What I dont quiet understand is, if this line
`Consultant.prototype = new Employee();`
is really ALWAYS wrong, or if this is useable in a situation like the question code where there are no parameters.

When I keep this line and do not replace it with your suggested line, I can still access the `this.paySchedule` you mentioned in your answer. Why is that?

Thanks for your explanation!

Comment: @T.Bob: If `Employee` doesn't accept any parameters or do anything else where it's assuming it's doing its main job (setting up an *instance*), then in mechanical terms, using `new Employee` functions. But it's not correct, and it's easy for `Employee` to start out not doing anything instance-specific, but then get edited later to do instance-specific work. So best to just do it properly from the outset.

Comment: @T.Bob: Re `paySchedule`: If you use `new Employee` to set up `Constructor.prototype`, you'll end up with `paySchedule` on `Constructor.prototype` -- and thus you'll see it on all `Constructor` instances. If you also have `Employee.call(this)` in `Constructor`, then `Employee` will add `paySchedule` to the instance as well. I'll add an example of what happens if you use `new Employee` instead of `Object.create(Employee.prototype)` *and* leave `Employee.call(this)` off and how it can All Go Very Wrong. :-)

Comment: Thanks, after every explanation I understand a little bit more. I am still a little bit confused about the actual difference between `new Employee` and `Object.create(Employee.prototype)`. I would be really glad if you could explain what exactly the difference between those two is. At the moment, the only difference for me is, that with the first I have the constructor included and with the latter not. Is there any other difference?

Thank your very much for your help, really really apprechiate this! :)

Comment: @T.Bob: Sorry, I really should have done that from the outset.

Comment: Oh I think I understand now! The `Consultant` class inherits from ONE Employee, meaning, that every `Consultant` instance accesses the same inherited properties from `Employee`.

So if I have 2 `Consultants`, their pointer to the `Employee`'s `staff` points to the same location, meaning they share this array?

So in a simple world, the `new Employee` could work, and as the question was pretty simple, it would work. But in a more complex question, this would not work anymore as this would lead to exact such problems?

Comment: @T.Bob: Exactly. I've also beefed up the beginning of the answer above to call out what `Object.create` does as opposed to what `new Employee` does. Happy coding!

Comment: Thank you very much for confirming and adding to the answer. This is probably one of the best explanations I have ever got, thank you SO MUCH!

Happy coding to you too! :)